# JUnit test data in static or non static methods

Tags: java, java-8, coding-style, junit4

Like to know which one is good.

I have to keep some JUnit test data in a different file. Lets call it as `TestingData.java`. I thought of doing it in two ways.

### First Way

**TestingData.java**

```
public class TestingData {
  protected String getHelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

### Second Way

**TestingData.java**

```
public class TestingData {
  public static String getHelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

I can call the **First Way** like this in my testing service by extends `TestingData` class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest extends TestingData {
  @Test
  public void helloWorldTest() {
    assertEquals("Hello World", getHelloWorld());
  }
}
```

calling **Second Way** in my testing service by calling the static function `TestingData.getHelloWorld()`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest {
  @Test
  public void helloWorldTest() {
    assertEquals("Hello World", TestingData.getHelloWorld());
  }
}
```

Like to know which way is better in clean code principle

Comment: Keep the data as close to the test code as possible. You need a very good reason to move it out of class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer might not be related to "clean code", but rather be different depending on your current and future use cases.

Extending the fixture class in the **First Way** creates an important limitation - you won't be able to extend any other base class, and such case happens quite often in unit testing.

A static method in the **Second Way** can't be overridden.

You could use a **Third Way**, an interface with a default method. This won't limit you to a specific base class, and its default method may be overridden if you need this in the future:

```java
public interface TestingData {
  default String getHelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest implements TestingData {
  @Test
  public void helloWorldTest() {
    assertEquals("Hello World", getHelloWorld());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple test classes sharing the same parent. you can define `abstract` class and puts all the common attributes and behavoirs.

, And I would recommend to declare the static content as `static final` not be hard coded.

in this way you can choose to create a method and call it from the child in each test cases, Like this:

```
public abstract class TestingData {
  
  private static final GET_HELLO_WORLD = "Hello World";

  public void setUp() {
      // common setUp
  }

  protected String getHelloWorld() {
    return GET_HELLO_WORLD;
  }
}
```

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest extends TestingData {

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
      super.setUp();
      // Add more settings
  }
  
  @Test
  public void helloWorldTest() {
    assertEquals("Hello World", getHelloWorld());
  }
}
```

---

, Or just call the constants from the child directly

```
public abstract class TestingData {
  
  protected static final GET_HELLO_WORLD = "Hello World";

  public void setUp() {
      // common setUp
  }
}
```

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest extends TestingData {

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
      super.setUp();
      // Add more settings
  }
  
  @Test
  public void helloWorldTest() {
    assertEquals(callTargetTestMethod(), GET_HELLO_WORLD);
  }
}
```